# What would happen if a Europa-like moon "thawed"?

Tags: planets, space, atmosphere, moons, solar-system

I have a planet and moon system orbiting a high mass star, something like a type A main sequence. Everything is only a short two billion years old, but the star is already starting to expand, warming the moon system of the planet. Aside from a captured planet, the largest moon of this super-Jupiter is a lot like a super-Europa. It has a layer of thick ice resting on a deep ocean of molten ice (commonly known as water), and little to no atmosphere.

What would happen when the moon warms up? Assuming it's protected by a magnetosphere from the gas giant, able to hold an atmosphere and surface liquid, what would become of the surface?

Some helpful details:
The moon is around twice the size of Europa, and had a similar composition in it's crust, being mostly ice. I'm not sure what would likely make up the rest, though, so let's say methane and frozen CO2. The gas giant is 1.7 Jovian masses.

Comment: If you want detailed information then you need to provide detailed inputs.  Is your super-Europa twice as massive as real Europa, or ten times as massive, or...?  Other than H2O, what is the ice layer composed of?  (This is the big one that will determine what the atmosphere will have in it.)

Comment: I believe it's important to explain Stack Exchange's and this Stack's expectations and intent. Stack Exchange is not a free research service. It's not meant or intended to replace an education. [Nor is it intended to replace research](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). While we're OK with people asking questions without a specific worldbuilding project going on, you're not supposed to ask questions *just because you're curious.* Stack Exchange prefers questions that lead to about a page-length answer, so "as much detailed information as possible" is *out of scope.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are asking a "What if X happened?" type of question

Comment: Thanks guys! ❤️

Comment: @JBH This question appears to be about worldbuilding; the opening of the question describes a science fictional premise the author is working on, and wants to know how it works. How is this different than asking about weather involving a fictional mountain range in proximity to a lake or something?  Or the effects of an unusual biology on shelter construction? The author is asking about building a fictional setting.

Comment: @L.Dutch I would argue I'm asking a "HOW would X happen" question.

Comment: @ScholarMoth Re "HOW would X happen." You are definitely not asking how the moon could be thawed. You are most certainly asking, "what happens after it thaws?" That kind of question is known as a [High Concept Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and for a variety of reasons, they're off-topic.

Comment: @Amadeus The difference was the OP's comment, now deleted, asking for as many details as possible and a line in the Q, now deleted, stating the OP was curious. I didn't challenge this as a worldbuilding question. My challenge was against the OP's expectations about this site and Stack Exchange. There are rules here and it's important to help people understand them before they develop bad habits. An example of failing to do that: we've had to occasionally take users to task for violating the "mindless social fun" prohibition even though they were asking worldbuilding questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is completely open-ended. The obvious answer is "it would melt. Water would make an atmosphere and start to be blown away by the solar wind." I need to ask OP why that isn't an adequate answer.

Comment: @JBH Alright, so what would be a better question? I'm mainly struggling with that. What I WANT to figure out is the consequences of a world like that, and I have no idea what to ask or where to ask. Any better place, if no question would work here, or am I in the dark?

Comment: @ScholarMoth Here's your problem, *no one knows.* We can imagine what might happen, but we can't explain what will happen. Thawing an entire moon and/or world is outside human experience and mathematics will only take you so far. From a worldbuilding perspective, the vaporizable materials will become atmosphere. The liquifyiable materials will become fluids. And what's left over is land. Will it be covered? That depends on how you design the world. Maybe that's the problem. It's your world, what do you want to have happen? (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... And therein lies an important point. This Stack's purpose is to help people build imaginary worlds. Questions of the form "I want X to happen, my starting point is Y, I researched Z but it didn't help me because of A. How can I rationalize X?" are spot-on our favorite. We're *really good* at questions like that. On the other hand, "My starting point is Y. Now what?" is simply off-topic because *anything* can happen - especially when you're considering cosmological time spans.

Comment: @JBH Completely fair, I'll try to keep that in mind for future questions. I just look for realism in my project, and sometimes I'm not sure if I'm missing something that someone else might know about, or if there's a glaring problem with my idea. I have a vague idea of what would happen when an ice moon melts, but I'm not sure. I have no idea what the implications of a completely water vapor atmosphere are. But, I can ask other sources questions like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the ice would melt and form a deep ocean, and the non-water materials would dissolve into the water, melt into the water, or become gases and be trapped in the water. You'll pretty much end up with a planetary ocean, perhaps with some ice left at the poles.

You'd get a thin (or thick, depending on how hot it got) atmosphere of water vapor, too.

Comment: It is possible some dense material trapped in the ice would move to the center to form a solid core. Iron meteorites and such.

Answer (score 2):

### A Moon of Water Vapor

It seems like this planet would first have a large amount of evaporating water, creating a thick, big atmosphere. Due to the greenhouse effect this would be compounded and the atmosphere would even more thick and incredibly hot.

Eventually, nearer to the middle, you would come to an ocean of water. I am not sure how thick this water would be; it might not even exist. Either way, it likely would be very far below the surface. Ice might exist somewhere too, but I also do not think it would be at the surface.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)#Internal_structure), "Europa probably contains a metallic iron core." This metal in the moon would stay in the middle, and all non-water materials would either go to the atmosphere or fall, depending on density. I expect meteorites would mostly fall down, with nitrogen, oxygen, and hydrogen adding to the atmosphere if present.